# stopping mouseDown propogation for textline

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

How do i stop textline from propogating(?) events down the application without destroying functions.

This is what i have

```
Application
  Component 1
     RichEditableTextfield
```

Component 1 listens for events in multiple childrens and looks for:

```
if (event.target is RichEditableTextfield) {
// Do stuff here...
} else {
// Do other stuff
}
```

But RichEditableTextfield sends MouseDown event on every textline and Component 1 gets confused and thinks i want to "Do other stuff" instead of "Do stuff here..." because event.target is TextLine.

Now i have this to stop the TextLines from propogating further:

```
private function stopTextLineEvents():void
{
    if (this.textFlow.flowComposer) {
        for (var i:int = 0; i < this.textFlow.flowComposer.numLines; i++) {
            var flowLine:TextFlowLine = this.textFlow.flowComposer.getLineAt(i);
            var textLine:TextLine = flowLine.getTextLine(true);

            if (textLine) {
                textLine.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,onTextLineDown);
                textLine.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,onTextLineDown);
            }

        }
    }
}

protected function onTextLineDown(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    event.stopPropagation();
    this.dispatchEvent(event.clone());
}
```

It almost works but my problem is that when i have multiple lines, every time i click on a line (that isn't the first line) the first line in the textfield get the anchor instead of the line i clicked.

Comment: Why not check for RichEditableText or TextLine?

Comment: Have you tried event.preventDefault( );

Comment: @Amy because i don't know how to access the RichEditableTextfield if the event.target is a TextLine, going parent.parent.parent isn't really a nice solution.

Comment: @The_asMan tried it, same problem happens, i can't select textlines that is below the first line for some reason.

Comment: Sometimes you have to do things that aren't pretty, just because of how the Framework is built.  If you can't listen directly to RichEditableText (and thus use currentTarget), you have no choice but to walk the tree.